# Intellij - SQL Query File

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a .sql file that contains various SQL queries that I run for testing and debugging an app.  When I load the app into Intellij Idea (12), it asks me for a SQL dialect (Oracle, in this case), and it insists on running the entire script.

I want to just run one particular SQL query in the file by hitting

I am pretty sure that I used to do this in v 11.  Is this still possible?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place a semi colon at the end of each line and then highlight the query you want to execute.